# Problem connecting SPRINGBOOT+JAVA W/ MS SQL SERVER

Tags: java

I'm getting this error when connecting Springboot with ms sql server:

> ERROR 16464 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: \org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection] with root cause
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target []

it is way longer..

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;databaseName=apiTest;integratedSecurity=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
pom.xml

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

repo

```
@Repository
public class CountryRepo {

    @/Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        String sql = "select nombre, capital, poblacion from Countries";

        List<Country> retorno = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new MyObjectRowMapper());

        return retorno;
    }

    private static final class MyObjectRowMapper implements RowMapper<Country> {
        public Country mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Country country = new Country();
            country.setName(rs.getString(1));
            country.setCapital(rs.getString(2));
            country.setPopulation(rs.getInt(3));

            return country;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class CountryController {

@Autowired
private CountryService countryService;

@Autowired
public void setcountryService(CountryService countryService) {
this.countryService = countryService;
   }

@GetMapping("/countries")
public List<Country> getCountries() {
return countryService.getAllCountries();
    }
}
service

@Service
public class CountryService {
private final CountryRepo countryRepo;
public CountryService(CountryRepo countryRepo) {
this.countryRepo = countryRepo;
    }
public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
return countryRepo.getCountries();
    }
}
```

AppConfig

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;databaseName=apiTest;integratedSecurity=true");
return dataSource;
    }
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

IDK if u need any more information. But SQL is running and I have already allowed tcp/ip in firewall and SQL SERVER and also configured the IP is SQL SERVER configuration